# submit specific form without use the javascript exist in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a lot of forms and i want to submit one form per click.
I use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){ 
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"function.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

All my forms are same like this

```
<form method='post' id='title' name='title'>
  <input type='hidden' name='test' value='test' >
    <button type='submit' name='submit'></button>
</form>
```

My script works fine! --until--

I add in my page a different form. For this form i dont want use javascript.
When i click this different form javascript shows up!

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your forms a unique ID then only the forms you want to submit, will be submitted using the javascript you want to use. e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#title").submit(function(){ /* <-- notice form#title */
        var str = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"function.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(html) {
                alert(html);
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

<!-- this form will attach to above JS -->
<form method='post' id='title' name='title'>
  <input type='hidden' name='test' value='test' >
    <button type='submit' name='submit'></button>
</form>
```